# Accessing Photoshop preferences

Tags: photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I'm trying to loop over the Photoshop preferences. This should be as straightforwards as

```
for (i = 0; i < app.preferences.length; i++)
{
   alert(app.preferences[i]);
}
```

only the object app.preferences doesn't have a length and accessing each item such as

```
alert(app.preferences.beepWhenDone); //bool
```

works, but is tedious and is also possibly version dependent. I know most of them are read-only, but I'm quite keen to list them all.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

`alert(app.preferences.reflect.properties.sort().join("\r"));`

Or actually, to also let you inspect the actual values, you could do something like this:

```
var prefsObject = app.preferences;
var prefs = app.preferences.reflect.properties.sort();
var prefString = "Photoshop Preferences\r";

for(var i = 0; i < prefs.length; i++) {
  try {
      prefString += prefs[i] + ": " + prefsObject[prefs[i]] + "\r";
  } catch (e) {
      prefString += prefs[i] + ": " + e.message + "\r";
  }

}

alert(prefString);
```